# React Typescript Storybook - String literal types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I want to use `String literal types` in my component and I want to able to select any of those strings in my story using Storybook.

The component can only receive 3 types of strings: `LATER` | `IMMEDIATELY` | `FCFS`

But, I have this error:

`Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"LATER" | "INMEDIATELY" | "FCFS"'.ts(2322) index.tsx(4, 3): The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LotteryCardInterface & { children?: ReactNode; }'`

Component:

```
interface LotteryCardInterface {
  type: 'LATER' | 'INMEDIATELY' | 'FCFS'
}

const LotteryCard: React.FC<LotteryCardInterface> = (props: LotteryCardInterface) => 
(<p>
    {props.type}
  </p>)

export default LotteryCard;
```

Story:

```
export default {
  title: 'organism|LotteryCard',
  component: LotteryCard,
  decorators: [withKnobs]
}

const label = 'type';
const options = {
  LATER: 'LATER',
  INMEDIATELY: 'INMEDIATELY',
  FCPS: 'FCPS',
};
const defaultValue = 'LATER';

export const Summary = () => {
  const value = radios(label, options, defaultValue);
  return (
    <LotteryCard
      type={value}
    />
  )
}
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Which of the expressions in your code triggers it? I suspect `<LotteryCard
      type={value}
    />`. In that case what does `radios` return?

Comment: radios return a string

Comment: So, that's the problem then - you cannot assign `string` type to `'LATER' | 'INMEDIATELY' | 'FCFS'` type. How `radios` is declared and implemented?